# NoSQL/MongoDB Style Query Engine in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I've built a [static website generator](https://github.com/balupton/docpad) which more or less converts markdown documents to html pages. Documents can have tags, which are useful for [discovering related documents](https://github.com/balupton/docpad/blob/2bcfd152b4b55bab8944c968b8bf093300925319/lib/docpad.coffee#L317) - and thus is the requirement for a query engine.

Right now I'm using MongoDB but as the application is coded in Node.js and due to the extreme lack of MongoDB support on Node.js hosts (so far no.de is the only one that I know of which supports mongodb), as well as  a static website generator having absolutely no need for data persistence, I'd like to remove MongoDB and just keep the query engine.

Are there any MongoDB/NoSQL like query engines coded natively in Node.js/javascript? Or is there a better solution I haven't thought of yet... :S

Thanks guys.

**Edit: If there is no such thing, who would like to build it with me? Post a comment if so :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created my own in Coffee-Script for use on the Server-Side with Node.js and Client-Side with Web-Browsers.
It supports all the same queries as MongoDb. Find it here:

https://github.com/bevry/query-engine

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/) which uses css selectors for querying js objects

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have an equivalent for `$in` queries yet, which is a requirement. Definitely on the right track though! Thanks :)

Comment: This has been discussed, and there is some aspect of this coming.  If you want to make a contribution follow @lloydhilaiel on twitter or join us at #jsonselect on freenode!

Answer (score 0):

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) has a REST API and jQuery plugin available.

For example see http://andreasohlund.net/2011/02/19/accessing-ravendb-using-jsonp/

Comment: Thanks mate, although it seems RavenDB requires installing - something which I'd prefer not to do. Really looking for a Node.js native solution - I'll make that more clear in the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at libgit2 which is a C library for git and also the gitteh module for node.js  This will give you a node wrapper around a git library - now you can have a local git repo that saves a versioned copy of your static files and serves it up via node.js. What more could you ask for? Plus push pull from github no problem - it knows the git protocols.
I haven't built this myself but happy to help if you want to do this